# multiply 2 subset of a df based on 2 other columns python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df such has:

```
df
Out[177]: 
              IV  maturity  strike
date                              
2000-12-29 0.435     0.083   0.600
2000-12-29 0.390     0.083   0.700
2000-12-29 0.331     0.083   0.800
2000-12-29 0.283     0.083   0.900
2000-12-29 0.391     0.250   0.600
2000-12-29 0.349     0.250   0.700
2000-12-29 0.304     0.250   0.800
2000-12-29 0.268     0.250   0.900
```

I am trying to create 4 new rows where maturity = 0 and IV is equal to the product of IV where maturity==0.083 IV and maturity==0.25 IV and'strike' match together such has   ( example: IV for strike 0.6 and and maturity 0.083 is 0.435 and IV for maturity 0.25 for strike 0.6 us 0.391, so 0.391*0.435

```
 Out[177]: 
                  IV  maturity  strike
    date                              
    2000-12-29 0.435     0.083   0.600
    2000-12-29 0.390     0.083   0.700
    2000-12-29 0.331     0.083   0.800
    2000-12-29 0.283     0.083   0.900
    2000-12-29 0.391     0.250   0.600
    2000-12-29 0.349     0.250   0.700
    2000-12-29 0.304     0.250   0.800
    2000-12-29 0.268     0.250   0.900
    2000-12-29 0.170     0.000   0.600
    2000-12-29 0.136     0.000   0.700
    2000-12-29 0.101     0.000   0.800
    2000-12-29 0.758     0.000   0.900
```

thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then multiple first and second column selected by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to new column `0`. Last [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.pivot(index='strike', columns='maturity', values='IV'))

df1.loc[:,0] = df1.iloc[:,0] * df1.iloc[:,1]

print (df1.unstack().reset_index(name='IV'))
    maturity  strike        IV
0      0.083     0.6  0.435000
1      0.083     0.7  0.390000
2      0.083     0.8  0.331000
3      0.083     0.9  0.283000
4      0.250     0.6  0.391000
5      0.250     0.7  0.349000
6      0.250     0.8  0.304000
7      0.250     0.9  0.268000
8      0.000     0.6  0.170085
9      0.000     0.7  0.136110
10     0.000     0.8  0.100624
11     0.000     0.9  0.075844
```